# How to compile source of Core and Service on WinRT?

Tags: windows-10-universal, windows-10-iot-core, alljoyn, windowsiot

We are trying to make the control panel service working on WinRT. However, we could not compile the code because we cannot find the namespace 'ajn'.

What we have done is:

- Download the core source and the service source from AllJoyn website.
- Setup a C++ uwp runtime component project and include all those source.
- Add C++ wrapper codes to use the control panel service.
- Setup another uwp blank app project, so it could use the wrapper codes to utilize contorl panel service.

However, we got stuck on compiling the codes, because the compiler could not find the all those classes under namespace ajn.

Where could we find the namespace? Or did we use the wrong source?

Thank you!

EDIT: 
We managed to find those file, However, some linking errors shown up. Is there any good document which shows making codes process for WinRT? Or is WinRT Code Generation is well configured at all? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the files are all in alljoyn_core folder, now the codes have been compiled. 
However, some linking errors shown up. Is there any good document which shows making codes process for WinRT? Or is WinRT Code Generation is well configured at all? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the Documentation on the Allseen Alliance's website. here is the link for the building Windows

[Building on Windows](https://allseenalliance.org/framework/documentation/develop/building/windows)

Just make sure to follow the steps after creating a new project in Visual Studio

Make sure you set the envionment variables correctly and avoid spelling mistakes. The spelling mistake cost me two to three days in finding the linking error.!